# Why am I getting dead code warning here in java?

Tags: java, dead-code

I'm getting dead code warning in eclipse from the `if(line == null)` statement to the `r.close()` statement.

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));

int counter = 0;

while(true)
{
    String line = r.readLine();
    counter++;

    if(line.contains(" = "))
    {
        String[] keyVal = new String[2];

        keyVal[0] = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(" = ") - 1);
        keyVal[1] = line.substring(line.indexOf(" = ") + 3);

        buffer.add(keyVal);
    }
    else
    {
        new Exception("Invalid expression at line " + counter + " in file " + file.getPath()).printStackTrace();
    }

    if(line == null) // dead code here
    {
        break;
    }
}

System.out.println("here is a dead code");

r.close(); // another dead code
```

Comment: Because if `line` were null, you'd have an exception at `line.contains(" = ")`.

Comment: Well, if `line` is `null`, then `if(line.contains(" = "))` will cause a `NullPointerException` - to start with. Try and avoid `while(true)` and `break`, it's just messy, have an actual exit condition from your loop you can easily reason about.  Also, you might like to have a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) as a better means for managing your resources

Comment: Also, if `line.contains(" = ")` is false, you throw an exception, so a whole bunch of code never runs

Comment: Not the answer, but the `new Exception...` line should start with `throw`. At the moment, the code creates an exception and does nothing with it.

Comment: @AlexTaylor, actually, there's a `printStackTrace()` at the end of that line.  However, this is kind of an abomination.  It misses the point of throwing and catching exceptions.  If OP wants to print an error message, they should just print an error message.

Comment: The code outside the while is also dead, because the break condition is dead and the while is an infinite loop, so the code will never be reached.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Yes, I missed that. Which means I change it to a recommendation: @Gergő Gutyina change it to a `throw`, and remove the `printStackTrace()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are operating on `line` with `if(line.contains(" = "))`.  If `line` was `null`, a `NullPointerException` would be thrown, which you are not catching.  Therefore, the `break;` statement can't be reached.  If the `if(line == null)` statement is reached, it's not `null`.  Logically, `break;` will never be executed, so it's unreachable.  It appears that Eclipse is detecting this.  Note that this will still compile with javac just fine; this is just Eclipse's warning.

Furthermore, if the `break;` is unreachable, then there is no way to end `while(true)`, so anything beyond the `while` block is unreachable.  So Eclipse warns on this too.

The usual way of reading a file line-by-line, checking the `line` for `null` to indicate end of the stream, is

```
String line;
while ( (line = r.readLine() ) != null)
{
    // rest of processing here
}
```

It's not the cleanest code, with an assignment in the same expression as an equality check, but it's the usual way of doing this kind of read-and-check operation.

This way the `while` statement can end normally, and then there is no need to check for `null` later.  That also makes any code following the `while` block reachable.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
if(line == null) 
{
    break;
}
```

before the

```
if(line.contains(" = "))
```

reason it is a dead code is because both if else statements can result in an exception , making any code after that a dead code.

Comment: Even better: he could put that check on the while itself, like `while((line = r.readLine()) != null)`